# Framer.js - "layer" parameter of drag events is undefined

Tags: coffeescript, event-handling, drag, framerjs

I've created a list with draggable list items in framer.js written in coffeescript.

The array "Layers" contains the single list items.

```
for i in [0..3]
    layer = new Layer width:listWidth, height:listHeight, y:i*yDistance, clip:false,
    borderRadius: 4, superLayer:canvas

    layer.listIndex = i

    layer.draggable.enabled = true
    layer.draggable.speedX = 0
    layer.draggable.speedY = 1

    Layers.push(layer)
```

When I now call a event listener on the list items the "layer" parameter is undefined

```
layer.on Events.DragMove, (event, draggable, layer) ->
    print layer
```

I need the layer element in the event function to manipulate it. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `draggable` declaration:

```
layer.on Events.DragMove, (event, layer) ->
    print layer
```

Alternatively, use the `this` keyword:

```
layer.on Events.DragMove, (event, layer) ->
    print this
```

With your code:

```
for i in [0..3]
    layer = new Layer width:listWidth, height:listHeight, y:i*yDistance, clip:false,
    borderRadius: 4, superLayer:canvas

    layer.listIndex = i

    layer.draggable.enabled = true
    layer.draggable.speedX = 0
    layer.draggable.speedY = 1

    Layers.push(layer)

    layer.on Events.DragMove, (event, layer) ->
        print layer
        print this
```